# Facebook pixel giving error of ViewContent and pageView

Tags: javascript, python, facebook-pixel

I am getting pageView and ViewContent error of facebook pixel on the product page of my e-commerce website. It is working fine on localhost and other pages of website, but showing error on product page. My website is in python and facebook code is placed into a common page and included on every [image]page.

```js
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
                    content_type: 'product',
                    content_ids: ['GPROD'+'{{ src.sku }}'],
                    content_name: '{{ product_obj.category_name }}',
                    content_category: '{{ product_cat_parents|last }}',
                    value: Math.round(parseFloat('{{ src.pricing.tax_exclusive_price_moq }}')),
                    currency: 'INR'
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem on code end. Your Facebook pixel is not activated. Just Goto Facebook and try to activate it.

Once activated init the facebook pixel before tracking code.

```
fbq("init", FACEBOOK_PIXEL);
```